# File "rollback" in any Java IDE

Tags: java, ide

Is it possible to set a "rollback point" in any Java IDE (Eclipse, NetBeans, IDEA), so that I can quickly get back to it if I don't like the change without going through the millions of Undo's?

I know that there's a best practice branch-commit quickly-merge, but that's not appropriate in current environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Eclipse**

Eclipse keeps a [local history](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-55.htm) of a file. Right-click in the file and choose Compare With -> History to view it.

It may be necessary to mark the 'Local Revisions' tool bar button in the History view to view them.

The local history can be configured via Window | Preferences, then General -> Workspace -> Local History

**NetBeans**

NetBeans has a local file history which acts similar to a versioning system. You can "rollback" your changes to a specific version of the file.

**IntelliJ IDEA**

IDEA has the similar [feature](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-local-history.html), and even supports [labels](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/putting-labels.html), which are put on the whole project tree.

Comment: But I don't see any way to mark specific state of a file, they're just marked with time label. Is there a way to mark them (create a specific "rollback point")?

Comment: I can't find any way to do it - the Comment column is read-only. I guess you'd just have to make a note of the timestamp - at least it should solve the many undos problem

Comment: I've edited your answer to incorporate info for all three IDEs. Hope it's ok and will help to ease future references.

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans has a local file history which acts similar to a versioning system. You can "rollback" your changes to a specific version of the file.

Comment: Eclipse also has a local history: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-55.htm

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, I think the [Local History](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-55.htm) could help